# VB Script Space

Tags: vbscript

I am in need of a vb script that will be used as a macro in excel.

I need the rows with data that have spaces to have the spaces removed. I know how to create a formula one cell at a time but I am clueless on how to do this on a large scale with a looping script. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use `Trim` to do the same on that column. that function would remove spaces from `pre` and `post` position of that string!

Comment: I am looking to remove the spaces in the string.. So 'PR 026R' would be 'PR026R'. and for it to look at each row in the column and "fix" it.

Comment: Which do you want? VBA or VBScript? Please correct your tags.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know that much about the micros, but in vb-script you can use following code :-

```
Option Explicit 
Dim objFso,strFileName,objFile
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")          
strFileName="C:\Documents and Settings\amolc\Desktop\test.txt"   ''Path of text file

Set objFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(strFileName,1)
strText = objFile.ReadAll
objFile.Close
strText = Replace(strText," ","",vbTextCompare)            ''Replace function to remove space
Set objFile = objFso.OpenTextFile(strFileName,2)
objFile.Write (strText)
objFile.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Columns("F:F").Select

Selection.Replace What:=" ", Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
```

I try to replace character space (" ") with none ("")